# How to fetch the middle mouse button in java?

Tags: java, events, mouse

I use `public boolean mouseDown(Event ev, int x, int y)` to detect a click of the mouse.
I can distinguish between the right mouse button (ev.metaDown() is true) and the left and middle.

How can i differentiate the left from the middle button?
Or if it is impossible with mouseDown, what should i use?

Comment: Which GUI are we talking about: SWT, Swing, or (classic) AWT?

Comment: awt (this is to get 10 chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ALT_MASK](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Event.html#ALT_MASK):

> This flag indicates that the Alt key was down when the event occurred. For mouse events, this flag indicates that the middle mouse button was pressed or released.

So your code might be:

```
if (ev.modifiers & Event.ALT_MASK != 0) {
    // middle button was pressed
}
```

Of course, all this is assuming you have a *very* good reason to use mouseDown in the first place, since it is deprecated. You should (probably) be using [processMouseEvent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#processMouseEvent(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) instead, which gives you a MouseEvent to play with.

Answer (score 1):

[mouseDown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#mouseDown%28java.awt.Event,%20int,%20int%29) is deprecated. All you need is accessible by the MouseEvent.[getButton](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getButton()). Track BUTTON3.

Comment: What should be used instead? ev.getButton() does not exist since ev is an Event not an MouseEvent.

Comment: you should implement the MouseListener interface, look at the code sample on this page: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: That should be BUTTON2, not BUTTON3. BUTTON3 is the right button.

Comment: BUTTON3 is the middle button, http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/how-to-implement-a-simple-double-buffered-animation-with-mouse-e.html

Answer (score 0):

This might do it:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isMiddleMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)

Haven't tried it myself.